# python - how to check if array contain value but in series

Tags: python

I want to check if the array contains value but in series example:

```
word = 'hello'
def splite(word):
    return list(word)
for i in range(len(word)):
    letter = splite(word[i])
    if 'e' in letter:
        print('e')
    if 'h' in letter:
        print('h')
```

the output is

```
eh
```

and I want the output to

```
he
```

I know because in the script the letter 'e' detect first but I want the letter 'h' detect first because in the word 'hello' h is first, how can I do that?

Comment: As your code, the output seems to be always `he` [Check This](https://onecompiler.com/python/3y6x5ad8v)

Comment: You need to iterate over the letters in the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a string is a list of characters, you dont need to split it. You can just iterate over it like it would be a 'normal' list:

```py
word = 'hello'
for i in range(len(word)):
    letter = word[i]
    if 'h' == letter:
        print('h')
    if 'e' === letter:
        print('e')
```

How did your code produce `eh`? When testing your code it always printed `he`. What is the actual goal of this code snipped?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your question title (how to check if array contains a value but in series), this is a great solution for your problem, as far as I understand it.

```
def check_substring(string, letters):
    word = list(string)
    return any(letters == word[i:i+2] for i in range(len(word) - 1))


word = "hello"
print(check_substring(word, ["h","e"]))
```